# how to transpose rows and columns in lightninig created by data Table in sfdc

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

how to transpose rows and columns in lightning created by data Table in sfdc

```
({
    fetchAc : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'Phone'},
                {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website', type: 'url '}
            ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccounts");
        action.setParams({
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you mean matrix transpose?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: No i want to move columns to left side vertically